# Why does my post request not send with the right header?

Tags: python, request

I have this python code:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic blablatoken', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
jsonBody = json.dumps(customer)
postResp = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=jsonBody)
```

When I execute this code, the server complains about a missing "Authorization" header. In the response I log I see this when executing this code:

```
print(postResp.request.headers)
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing. If I use your code as presented in this question, `postResp.request.headers` shows the expected `Authorization` header.

Comment: Try this: response = requests.post(url, headers=json.dumps(customer), json=json)

Comment: Your code works fine for me, `postResp.request.headers` is `{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'Basic blablatoken', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '0'}`